# Where to start with creating a custom XML export / feed module for magento?

Tags: php, xml, api, magento, feed

I know this is a BIG question, but i am looking to integrate magento with mobi-cart and I wondered where the best place to start with something like this would be?

I need to export certain fields into and xml feed that updates mobi-cart. Their API is here: http://www.mobi-cart.com/docs/api/index.html

I would like some pointers - is it just PHP and XML or will i need other tech? Would i have to make a module for magento that can export XML?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@@willywonka --Nice post- i used this link

http://www.YOURSHOP.com/api/?wsdl

If you get an XML response then soap is installed on the server and magento is ready to conenct.. if you get somthing like "..unable to laod soap..."  you will have to install soem things.

---

to export you will need to use profiles. It runs a profile and creates a file on the server. i am not sure if you can a feed. but it migh tbe possible using the download option.

[Open Image in new tab for good resolution] 
[image: Open Image in new tab for good resolution]

Then when you press "Run Profile" a windows will popup and you can use the Link to creat the feed
Like mine is ..

> http://www.MYSHOP.co.uk/index.php/admin/system_convert_gui/run/id/7/

Afterwards i download the file using a .net program and process the data. once i am done i upload to ftp for example and run another profile to import the stuff.

In you case your program will use the file to get data in send it into the API somehow.

---

That was the easy way- but not very great.

The magento API is explained here

http://www.magentocommerce.com/support/magento_core_api

and looks like a nightmare to get to work and it seems like you can only do it if you have ssh access to the server to install things to it. But that would be the ideal way for these to API's to communicate.

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer and voting up for people who have helped you. :D I have also looked into how to get the API working in .net you have to use API v2 to do that.. and there is little documented on it. There is more help with PHP api V2 and might also help you